# Java Thread : object has both synchronized and not synchronized methods

Tags: java, multithreading, synchronized

suppose there are 2 threads used in this  demo.Suppose `increment()` code block executes first and acquires the monitor on the current object.does other thread will not be able to execute the method `decrement()` ? .

can anyone help me understand?

if I ran the application, other thread able to execute non-synchronized method even though is lock on the object hold by thread that sleeps `10000 ms` .

```
package com.learn.threads;

import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;

public class ThreadDemo {

    int sharedVariable;

    public ThreadDemo(int sharedVariable) {
        this.sharedVariable = sharedVariable;
    }


    public synchronized void increment() throws InterruptedException {
        Thread.sleep(10000);
        this.sharedVariable++;

    }

    public void decrement() throws InterruptedException {
        this.sharedVariable--;

    }


    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {

        ThreadDemo task = new ThreadDemo(0);

        ExecutorService incrementExecutorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(2);
        for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
            incrementExecutorService.submit(() -> {
                try {
                    task.increment();
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            });
            Thread.sleep(5000);
            incrementExecutorService.submit(() -> {
                try {
                    task.decrement();
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            });

        }
        Thread.sleep(35000);
        incrementExecutorService.shutdown();
        System.out.println(task.sharedVariable);

    }
}
```

Comment: since decrement isn't synchronized it doesn't try to acquire any locks and just goes ahead and does its thing. but its changes may not be visible to other threads. also the increment and decrement operators are not threadsafe. so this code has several issues.

Comment: Thank you. Only thread that executes synchronized methods/blocks checks for the lock on the object.

Comment: The code contains a race condition because decrement isn't mutually exclusive with the increment or concurrent decrements. So you can loose updates. Also it contains a data race because the read/write of the variable (due to the non synchronized decrement method) isn't ordered by a happens before relation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, it won't.

1. `synchronized` on a method is just syntax sugar for wrapping the entire body of the method in `synchronized (X) {}`, where X is `this` for instance methods and `YourClass.class` for static ones. It is a severe design error unless you document the locking behaviour of your class if you do this - anytime you lock on stuff other code could get a reference to (`this` and `YourClass.class` are usually public), you need to document this, and endeavour to support what you document in future v ersion.
2. `synchronized` interacts with other synchronized blocks on the same reference, and on `thatRef.wait/notify/notifyAll()` and **nothing else**. It has zero effect on its own, you always need 2 different threads both hitting a synchronized block, synchronizing on the same thing, or it does nothing useful.

The code snippet as pasted is broken: If some thread calls `decrement()`, other threads may or may not observe this, as no CBCA relationship is established. Any code that reads `sharedVariable` needs to lock on `ThreadDemo`, and the `decrement` method needs to gain a `synchronized` attribute.

Note that the job of having an incrementable/decrementable thing already exists: `AtomicInteger`, you should be using that instead if this is your actual intent (but I'm assuming you wrote this merely as an example).

NB: The java memory model is best understood as an evil coin. Evil in that it is out to mess with you: To have code that works great every time and in all your tests, and the first week you put it live on the production servers, and then just as that important customer gets a demo, it breaks. You must write code such that the VM never flips that coin (or rather, that the results of the flip do not affect your code), and there is no easy way to know that the evil coin is being flipped. Threading is very difficult to get right, yup. Why do you think most multithreaded code out in the real world does **all** inter-thread communication via a message bus or transactional database? The coin is flipped anytime any code touches any field anywhere, and the result of the coin decides whether the thread uses a local clone copy of that field, or if it reads from the shared copy. Thus, `sharedVariable--` might result in a decrement that only your thread can see, or all threads can see, depending on the result of the evil coin. If what your code does depends on the flip, you messed up, and your tests aren't going to catch it. You can avoid the coin flip by establishing a comes-before relationship between `sharedVariable--` and whatever cod reads `sharedVariable`. `synchronized` is one of a few ways to establish such a relationship. Search the web for 'java memory model' 'synchronized' for more info - but note that this is very complex stuff.